# Dynamically fill form fields according to value change of a dropdown before submitting form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, simple-form

I am working on an order form of a RoR project and want to fill buyer info with existing customer info in database. So I need to select a customer name from a dropdown(select field) then fill in buyer info fields (name, phone, email, address like so) with selected customer's information.

Therefore my question is, what's the preferred practise of doing this? My thought is something like an Ajax call with GET method to get json format data then use jQuery to fill in or change buyer info fields. Is it the correct "rails way" to achieve this function?

BTW, the whole order form is simple_form, and buyer info fields are all in a simple_fields_for section. If this helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "standard" way of doing this would be via ajax (just send a `JSON` request to your `users#show` action, and it should return the user data you request -- I'll write in a second).

---

From your question, it seems you should do something else.

> fill buyer info with existing customer info in database

This is *bad practice* -- it will lead to duplicate entries in your db.

The way this should be done is to take advantage of the [`associations`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) inside Rails to allow you to *associate* a `customer` with new buyer info:

```
#app/models/order.rb
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :customer #-> requires "customer_id" in "orders" table
end

#app/models/customer.rb
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :orders
end
```

This will create an associative `customer` object on your `order`: `@order.customer` which will return the data in your other db table.

You'll have to make sure you populate the `customer_id` param for your new `Order` object:

```
#app/controllers/orders_controller.rb
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @customers = Customer.all
      @order = Order.new
   end

   def create
      @order = Order.new order_params
      @order.save
   end

   private

   def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit(:customer_id, :etc, :etc)
   end
end

#app/views/orders/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @order do |f| %>
   <%= f.collection_select :customer_id, @customers, :id, :name %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

---

**JS**

You *can* use what you're asking with the above code, too.

You basically need to send an Ajax (JSON) request to your `customers#show` action, which will return the relevant fields for a specific `customer` to your JS:

```
#app/controllers/customers_controller.rb
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
   respond_to :json, :html, only: :show

   def show
      @customer = Customer.find params[:id]
      respond_with @customer
   end
end

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("change", "select#customer_id", function(e){
   $.ajax({
      url: "customers",
      dataType: "json",
      data: { id: $(this).val() },
      success: function(data){
         // Output returned data in form
      }
   });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to populate a form based on a user's choice then you'll absolutely need to use some kind of javascript solution.  Either make an AJAX call, or if it's feasible(ie. you don't have that too many customers to serialize in this way and it's not a security or performance concern) you can preload the customer data as json into your front end javascript like so(in your view):

```
<script>
   var customerData = JSON.parse(<%= @customers.to_json %>);
</script>
```

And then just have the selected user's data populate the form based on the data in that variable.

This would make for a faster and smoother user experience, as well as being easier on the backend not having to make an AJAX call every time the user changes the value of that select box.